# Curly Quote usage in XeTeX via LyX

Tags: fonts, lyx, fontspec

I have this preamble in my LyX document:

```
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Contextuals=Alternate,Numbers=Lining,SmallCapsFeatures={Kerning=Uppercase}}
%\setmainfont{Calluna}
%\setsansfont{Calluna Sans}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Lining},Ligatures={Historic,Rare,Discretionary,TeX},Contextuals=Swash]{Calluna}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

and got this output: 
[image]
Notice the use of curly quotation marks appropriate to the language.

As soon as I remove the `Ligature={...}` part of the `\setmainfont`, I get this output:
[image]

It is also the case if I uncomment `\defaultfontfeatures`, `\setmainfont` and comment out `\setmainfont [...],Liga...` right afterwards.

I cannot seem to pinpoint where the option to have "curly quotes" used by default (which is what I see in the LyX menus) in XeTeX.

Comment: So don't uncomment or comment them. Sorry but I don't see the problem. `Ligatures=TeX` is enabling the emulation of standard TeX ligatures which are not supported by non-TeX fonts. Obviously if you disable that emulation, the ligatures won't be emulated.

Comment: I'm even less clear what you are asking now you have answered your question. Essentially, your question says, 'If I do X or Y, bad things happen'. Not sure what the question is but maybe 'why?'. Your answer is, 'do not-X or not-Y' which is in the question. I'm confused.

Comment: I am new to this LaTeX and XeTeX thing; I wasn't aware of the `Ligatures=TeX` function. I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: I thought `Ligatures=TeX` was introducing the logos common to TeX and LaTeX into the document. I actually stole the preamble bit from a different answer because I am not familiar enough with the documentation or the use of `\fontspec` to know what `TeX` meant. It was my ignorance, and I was asking out of desperation.

Comment: That really never occurred to me. Huh. May I suggest that you take a look at `fontspec`'s manual? It is pretty good with lots of examples and I think you will find the whole thing a bit less mysterious if you get some sense of how things are working. (Not everything but a kind of basic idea of how the land lies.) I'm glad I figured out what you were asking enough to make some sense, anyhow. One thing to notice is that your original question wasn't a question. Had you said 'When I remove..., then.... Can somebody explain why?' it would have been a lot clearer. That is, make it a *question* ;).

Comment: In general, something is not a bug in LyX unless you can reproduce it without a custom preamble in which case please post the minimal example LyX file, not the TeX output (or post this in addition).

Comment: @cfr, duly noted.

Comment: @scottkosty the "bug" was my lack of understanding basic documentation on the use of `\fontspec` in the LaTeX preamble in LyX. I will try to avoid panicking next time ;)

Comment: Not a problem! I was just giving a general rule of thumb in case it helps narrow down the bug search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that various features of traditional TeX/LaTeX and of traditional TeX fonts are not supported by the newer TeX engines which do not use the same fonts. This is their strength but sometimes their weakness.

There are actually two stages to the production of double curly quotes in LaTeX. The first is the recognition of ` to produce a single left quote, and of ' to produce a single right one. The second involves ligatures defined in the TeX font files which say that when two single left quotes occur in succession, the double left quote should replace them and similarly for the right quotes.

Since XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX handle both input encodings and fonts differently, none of this works out-of-the box. `fontspec` provides easy access to a feature which emulates this behaviour so that traditional TeX code continues to produce the results expected.

If you do not enable this feature, there is no emulation. So, if you want the emulation, don't disable the feature.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in another Stack. Pragmatically speaking:

The answer is to add `Ligatures={TeX}` to the `\setmainfont`, or `\defaultfontfeatures`.